# Copy entire text file into 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I want to copy an entire text file into a dynamically initialized 2D array. I have at first counted the no.of line present in text file and then

```
file = (char **) malloc (sizeof(char*) * total_lines) ;

for (i = 0; i < total_lines; i++)
    file[i] = (char *) malloc (sizeof (char) * MAX_CHAR) ;
```

Where `MAX_CHAR` is predefined as `1024`.
Now I'm just copying the file line by line into array

```
k = 0 ;
while (fgets (line, sizeof(line), fp))
    strncpy (file[k++], line, MAX_CHAR) ;
```

But my program crashes here.

Edit

```
char line[1024] ;

fp = fopen (filename, "r"))
//total lines
while (fgets (line, sizeof(line), fp))
        printf ("%d. %s", ++i, line) ;
total_lines = i - 1 ;
```

Comment: You should show the declaration of line.

Comment: And the reason you're not just `fgets()`-ing right into your buffers you just allocated in your pointer array? Or why you have no limit on the top-end of your line-reading loop, when clearly you have a top-end on the number of lines you can store.

Comment: You're sure you're not reading in more than `total_lines` lines from the file? How/where is `total_lines` defined?

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
total_lines = i - 1 ;
```

You are setting `total_lines` to the number of lines in the file minus 1. This means that you won't allocate enough memory for all the lines, and trying to read the last line will read past the end of the allocated `file` array.